# Best way to store U.S. phone numbers ( NANP)

Tags: mysql, couchdb

I have requirement to store  NANP(North American Numbering Plan) numbers. This means I don't care and no need to bother about international numbers.

Numbering plan goes like this :
NPA-NXX-XXXX

I would filter & strip extra space or dash(-) to make into 10 digit correct format. Currently we use MySQL and CouchDB for some other stuff but would prefer to keep in MySQL DB as preferred storage system. 
I'm looking for fast read operation to match numbers during runtime and write can be little slow as mostly insert/update will happen in off hours.

Since it is given that NPA & NXX will never start with 0  so if we can separate 
them and they can be used as integer type in case of want to breakdown.

For NoSQL case, it is possible to generate  separate document for each area code and then further isolate NXX & XXXX.
For RDBMS case, a full number can be stored as indexed integer for fast accessibility.

What would be the best database design to store these numbers ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm looking for fast read operation to match numbers during runtime

With CouchDB you can store every number as ID of a doc e.g.

```
{
  _id: "NPA-NXX-XXXX",
  _rev: "1-..."
}
```

To match any number you send a lightweight

```
HEAD path/to/CouchDB/dbname/NPA-NXX-XXXX
```

and it will respond with the statuscode 200 (has matched) or 404 (no match).

Write operations can be done in big bulks (`/dbname/_bulk_docs`).

Because the numbers are stored as id's the primary index of CouchDB can be used for the HEAD requests (as described above) - that means that every write is immediately available for reads.